# Проблемы при web-scrapping с кодировкой

Tags: python

Пытаюсь веб-скрепнуть azlyrics.com (знаю что противоречит лицензии, для собственного опыта), при скреппинге текст приходит в таком формате: ÐÐµÑÑÐ¼ â Ð»ÐµÐ´ÐµÐ½ÑÑ, Ð´Ð¸ÑÑÐ¸Ð´Ðµ â ÑÐ¸ÑÐ¸Ð½. Пытался сделать encode("utf-8"), не помогает, загуглил декодеры - вообще не распознают такой текст, текст при этом на сайте на кириллице. В консоли выглядит так: [image: скрин с консоли] . Кто-нибудь видел такую кодировку, как её расшифровать и получить кириллицу? С кодом всё норм, всё парсится, использую request и beautifulsoup4, проблема именно при попытке украсть текст

Comment: beautifulsoup4(res.content, 'lxml')

Comment: омг спасибо) использовал  (rest.text, "html.parser"), заработало

Comment: res.content более предпочтительнее меньше проблем с кодировкой